# Comparing defined raw data using preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a defined raw data in my header file (which is generated automatically), like this:

```
#defined RAW_DATA 0x11, 0x20, 0x55, 0x00, x044
```

The aim is to check a specific parameter of RAW_DATA in compilation time and if it is wrong throw an #error.

For instance, During the compilation, the preprocessor should check if 2nd parameter of RAW_DATA (in this case 0x20) is really 0x20, if it is not throw an #error.

The main problem, how to access the specific parameter in defined RAW_DATA, is it somehow possible?

P.S. I am using Keil compiler in C.

Comment: What do you intend to gain from checking this `#define`d constant at compile time? The value in the check itself is also a preprocessor constant - would you then have second check that the `0x55` in the check is `0x55`? If you are generating the `RAW_DATA` programmatically, include the check in the generator program. If you are generating it by hand, read it after typing it in…

Comment: @D.Mantas Please elaborate you question. RAW_DATA's 1st parameter is 0x11 2nd 0x20, ... what do u want to check here. in which scenario preprocessor should throw error ?

Comment: @Let Us Embeded Sorry for that, I have updated. The 2nd parameter is 0x20.

Comment: @Arkku The reason why I need to check, is that the header file is generated automatically and I can't change anything in the generating program. And sometimes its generated parameters are wrong. So the user during the compilation would see that the parameter is wrong and should go to the .h file and change the parameter to the correct one.

Comment: use `boost/preprocessor` if you can use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define RAW_DATA 0x11, 0x20, 0x55, 0x00, x044
#define X_GET_SECOND_PAR(par) GET_SECOND_PAR(par)
#define GET_SECOND_PAR(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5) p2

#if X_GET_SECOND_PAR(RAW_DATA) != 0x20
#error "2nd parameter shall be 0x20"
#endif
```

For specific parameter checking. It's not elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Define a macro like this

```
#defined RAW_DATA 0x11, 0x20, 0x55, 0x00, x044
#define RAW_DATA_PARAM_1(param1,param2,param3,param4,param5) param1 
#define RAW_DATA_PARAM_2(param1,param2,param3,param4,param5) param2
#define RAW_DATA_PARAM_3(param1,param2,param3,param4,param5) param3
#define RAW_DATA_PARAM_4(param1,param2,param3,param4,param5) param4
#define RAW_DATA_PARAM_5(param1,param2,param3,param4,param5) param5

#if RAW_DATA_PARAM_1(RAW_DATA) != 0x11
#error "wrong raw data param 1"
#elif RAW_DATA_PARAM_2(RAW_DATA) != 0x20
#error "wrong raw data param 2"
#elif RAW_DATA_PARAM_3(RAW_DATA) != 0x55
#error "wrong raw data param 3"
#elif RAW_DATA_PARAM_4(RAW_DATA) != 0x00
#error "wrong raw data param 4"
#elif RAW_DATA_PARAM_5(RAW_DATA) != 0x44
#error "wrong raw data param 5"
#endif
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me and `clang`, copypasted directly from here - `RAW_DATA` is interpreted as only one argument to the macros, not expanded to five. I believe the extra level of indirection is required as per accepted answer, so I'm curious: did you get this to work on some compiler?